# Storing variables in batch from another variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that does a bunch f things already and been trying to expand it to get some data from an ini file.

The ini file for example looks like this

```
[Settings1]
Text=Text
Text1=Text
Text2=Text

[Settings2]
Text=Text
Text1=Text
Text2=Text
```

I have figured out a way to get the section I require with the following batch

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "file=settings.ini"
set "section=[Settings1]"

set flag=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%# in ("%file%") do (
    set line=%%#
    ::trim
    for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("!line!") do set "line=%%a"
    set f=!line:~0,1!
    if "!f!" neq ";" (
        if !flag! equ 1 (
            ::for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ("!line!") do (
            for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ("%%#") do (
                set "!section!.%%a=%%b"

            )
        )

        if "!f!" equ "[" (
            if "!line!" equ "%section%" (
                set flag=1
            ) else (
                set flag=0
            )
        )       
    )
)

set %section%
```

This then outputs the following

```
Settings1.Text=Text
Settings1.Text1=Text
Settings1.Text2=Text
```

What I want to be able to do but cannot work out how to do is to take in each of these outputs and assign the value so just the 'Text' after the equals sign to its own variable that can then be recalled later in my script

I can display each row by doing the following

```
set %section%.Text
set %section%.Text1
set %section%.Text2
```

This will then output the following on screen

```
[Settings1].Text=Text
[Settings1].Text1=Text
[Settings1].Text2=Text
```

I am aiming to get the string after the = sign in to new variables I can use

```
set NOP=%section%.Text
set AIR=%section%.Text1
set TER=%section%.Text2
```

This however is not assigning the values to the variables - any ideas on what I have missed?

**Edit - becasue unclear output**

So if I run the script abvoe it outputs all the settings from the settings.ini that I require in the following way - I believe the set %section% command is doing this so at the moment it will output the following

```
[Settings1].Text=Text
[Settings1].Text1=Text
[Settings1].Text2=Text
```

So the script is locating the part of the settings.ini file I want it too. And bringing back the settings.

I need to get the value of each of these three settings brought back in to variables I can use elsewhere in my script. So anything after the = sign in this example they all say 'Text'

I have tried to do this with the following

```
set NOP=%section%.Text
set AIR=%section%.Text1
set TER=%section%.Text2
```

However if I then echo these out I get

```
[Settings1].Text
[Settings1].Text2
[Settings1].Text3
```

But I was expecting it to be

```
Text
Text
Text
```

Because I can then use these else where in the script.

Comment: ok, so to clarify, you want the text after equal sign only?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard correct, stored in a variable so I can use it to set a global environment.

Comment: ok, but you want the text after the equal sign to be the variable name, or value?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard to be the value the variable name can be anything.

Comment: Well, you're already doing it. :) it is because you are using set to show the values instread of `echo`ing them.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Its not working if I echo it before i set it I get [Settings1].Text without the value showing. If I do set NOP=%section%.Text and then echo NOP get the same response

Comment: ok, this is closed as you have another question already. Moving to that one.